# How to use try/except in a for loop AND append the result to a dataframe

Tags: python, for-loop, try-except

I am trying to only get info from an API for only the rows which do not have an error. I have been trying the try/except technique and append the non-error rows to final_dataframe. But when I check final_dataframe, the variable is not saved with the result of the for loop (even though I write .append)

```
final_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_cols)

for i in stocks['Symbol'][:20]:
    try:
        url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={i}&apikey={key}&outputsize=compact'
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        final_dataframe = final_dataframe.append(pd.Series([i,
                                                            data['Time Series (Daily)'][last_refresh]['5. adjusted close'],
                                                            'N/A'],
                                                           index = my_cols),
                                                 ignore_index = True)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: If nothing is being appended, you must be getting an error every time. Add `print` statements to see what's happening.

Comment: _Never_ blindly catch all errors and then silently discard them. You should study your code to understand what errors it can throw without indicating a serious problem, and handle those specific errors. Anything else should remain uncaught or should print a message telling you what went wrong.

Comment: You are only processing 20 items, you should print every exception and every append to you dataframe.    Right now you have no assurance that any elements were saved.